# Read forum content

Tags: screen-scraping

Hi there friends
I am looking if there is a mechanism using php or objective c, whichever - to read and interact with a forum

Let's say i would like a user to remotely using a differnet website/program to:

```
1. Login into a forum
2. View posts
3. Subscribe for posts etc etc
```

Is there any way to do this? Any helper libraries?
I would like to know how i should go about it

Any suggestions will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with python, you could try mechanise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but am a python noob, more into php - i saw there is a mechanize for php, but how reliable is it?
But the way i see it, its kind of a web content parser, i am looking for something that can read forums, make new posts, may be even register to that forum